# How to Scroll multiple Textfields together in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

I have a situation where 2 Textfields are placed inside a Stack Widget overlapping one another. Is there anyway i can scroll both the textfields together vertically if the data exceeds the size of the screen?

```
Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 0, 0),
                  child: SyntaxView(
                      code: codeController.text,
                      syntax: Syntax.C,
                      syntaxTheme: SyntaxTheme.gravityDark(),
                      withZoom: true,
                      withLinesCount: true),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 362,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(55, 12, 0, 0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    scrollPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    focusNode: codeFocus,
                    controller: codeController,
                    autofocus: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: null,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0x00ffffff),
                      // color: Colors.yellow,
                      height: 1.35,
                      fontFamily: "CodeFont",
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        CODE = value;
                        // print("X : ${codeController.text}");
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Use `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way way to handle that situation is to wrap your content in a ListView, which handles scrolling of its children. Here's a snippet from the [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) docs as an example:

```dart
ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
  ],
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html